# Call generic method with type of generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class B that has the following method signature:

```
static <T> T parse(String input, Class<T> target)
```

And I have a generic class A that is defined as follows:

```
class A<J>
```

In a method of class A I now want to call the parse method of class B so the method returns an object of type J. As J is known at compile time when I instantiate A I expect there is a way to do so.

Comment: So J is defined at runtime or a type parameter?

Comment: If the class of `J` is known at compile time, you can just pass it as the second argument to the parse method, as `J.class`.  If it's a type parameter, you can't.